# Arbitrary Key-Value Pairs in the Django Admin in a Tabular inline like format

Tags: python, json, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a Model with a TextField full of Json. The Json is always a single dict of key/value pairs. Both the Key and the Value are always strings.

I want to represent this (for viewing and editing) in a TabularInline-like format. Admin users must be able to add arbitrary keys.

Is there an existing package or simple method that allows this?

django-jsonfield has me hand writing the json by hand.

django-submodel gives my a StackedInline, and won't let me add keys.

django-SplitJSONWidget-form likewise won't let me add keys.

Comment: So you want to represent each key & pair in a json field as separate inputs in a row?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Each pair is a row in a table. I can add more rows, and edit both key and value. (Keys won't be edited often, but I must have the ability.)